# Get cell color in MS Word

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop, office-2007

in microsoft word I can open a document and get a text for a cell like this (office interop):

```
app.Tables[1].Cell(2, 2).Range.Text;
```

But I cannot find a property that can return this exact cell color. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the `Shading` property (`app.Tables[1].Cell(2, 2).Shading;`).

EDIT

To address your comment:  I don't believe there is a better way to get the color.  The `BackgroundPatternColorIndex` and `ForegroundPatternColorIndex` return values of the WdColorIndex enumeration; they have a numeric value that is not related to the RGB color.  For example, `wdRed` has a value of `6` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb237561(v=office.12).aspx for more information).

If you want the RGB values, as you may have guessed, you would use `BackgroundPatternColor` and `ForegroundPatternColor` rather than `...ColorIndex`.  But it sounds like you're looking for a string name rather than a numeric value.

Comment: That is cool! I was able to get color using this: wd.Tables[1].Cell(2, 2).Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex.ToString(); The only problem I experience is that it returns this string: "wdRed". How Can I get rid of wd natevly? I don't mind just stripping first two characters, but I assume there should be a better way.